# How do I extract strings from a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a return from an api function that gives me a dict like this:

```
{'result_index': 0,
 'results': [{'final': True,
   'alternatives': [{'transcript': "tickets are available ",
     'confidence': 0.49}]},
  {'final': True,
   'alternatives': [{'transcript': 'everything in the mail ',
     'confidence': 0.61}]},
  {'final': True,
   'alternatives': [{'transcript': 'thanks one all ',
     'confidence': 0.73}]}]}
```

There could be any number of transcripts included, including 0.
How do I extract all the transcripts into one string so it would be like this:

```
 'tickets are available everything in the mail thanks one all '
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Create an empty list. Loop through the first array, loop over the `results`, append each `transcript` to the array. Join the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want the transcript of the first alternative, the following code should work:

```
response = {
    "result_index": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "final": True,
            "alternatives": [
                {"transcript": "tickets are available ", "confidence": 0.49}
            ],
        },
        {
            "final": True,
            "alternatives": [
                {"transcript": "everything in the mail ", "confidence": 0.61}
            ],
        },
        {
            "final": True,
            "alternatives": [{"transcript": "thanks one all ", "confidence": 0.73}],
        },
    ],
}

transcripts = ""
for res in response["results"]:
    transcripts += res["alternatives"][0]["transcript"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work on all results/alternatives/transcripts.

```py
d = {'result_index': 0,
 'results': [{'final': True,
   'alternatives': [{'transcript': "tickets are available ",
     'confidence': 0.49}]},
  {'final': True,
   'alternatives': [{'transcript': 'everything in the mail ',
     'confidence': 0.61}]},
  {'final': True,
   'alternatives': [{'transcript': 'thanks one all ',
     'confidence': 0.73}]}]}

l = []

for x in d["results"]:
    for y in x["alternatives"]:
        l.append(y.get("transcript", ""))

print("".join(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be

```py
output = "".join(k.get('transcript', "") for res in response['results'] for k in res.get('alternatives', []))
```

Using get with alternative defaults here as you've said that there might be nothing in there. Assuming that there are always results. If not, just use `response.get('results', {}).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, including looking out for missing elements:

```
res = {'result_index': 0,
 'results': [
    {'final': True,
   'alternatives': [
        {'transcript': "tickets are available ",
     'confidence': 0.49
        }
      ]
    },
    {'final': True,
   'alternatives': [
        {'transcript': 'everything in the mail ',
     'confidence': 0.61
        }
      ]
    },
    {'final': True,
   'alternatives': [
        {'transcript': 'thanks one all ',
     'confidence': 0.73
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

ts = [
    alt.get('transcript','')
    for r in (res['results'] if res.get('results') else [])
    for alt in (r['alternatives'] if r.get('alternatives') else [])
]
print("".join(ts))
```

Output:

```
tickets are available everything in the mail thanks one all
```